# Is Maximum monotone NAE3SAT APX-hard?

Tags: approximation-hardness

I know that monotone NAE3SAT is NP-complete. I also know that MAXNAE3SAT is APX-complete. Note that I am using a monotone formula to mean with with no negated literals anywhere. Anyway, my question is that is the maximization version of this problem, monotone MAXNAE3SAT, still APX-complete?